# Implementing weak intrusive pointers in C++

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, weak-references

> Weak pointers are like smartpointers, except that references from weak
>   pointers do not prevent garbage collection, and weak pointers must
>   have their validity checked before they are used.

In our project (Linderdaum Engine http://www.linderdaum.com) we use intrusive pointers. To avoid circular references and islands of isolation we have implemented weak intrusive pointers the following way:

```
namespace LPtr
{
    clPtr<iObject> GetObjectsGraphPtrWrapper( sEnvironment* Env, iObject* Obj, size_t Generation );
};

/// Intrusive weak smart pointer
template <class T> class clWeakPtr
{
public:
    /// default constructor
    clWeakPtr(): Env( NULL ), FObject( NULL ), FGeneration( 0 ) {}
    explicit clWeakPtr( T* Ptr )
     : Env( Ptr ? Ptr->Env : NULL )
     , FObject( Ptr )
     , FGeneration( Ptr ? Ptr->FGeneration : 0 ) {}
    explicit clWeakPtr( const clPtr<T>& Ptr )
     : Env( Ptr ? Ptr->Env : NULL )
     , FObject( Ptr.GetInternalPtr() )
     , FGeneration( Ptr ? Ptr->FGeneration : 0 ) {}
    clPtr<T> Lock() const
    {
        clPtr<iObject> P = LPtr::GetObjectsGraphPtrWrapper( Env, FObject, FGeneration );

        return P.DynamicCast<T>();
    }
private:
    sEnvironment* Env;
    T*            FObject;
    size_t        FGeneration;
};
```

`GetObjectsGraphPtrWrapper` is here just for the sake of forward declarations and does roughly this:

```
LMutex Lock( &FObjectsGraphMutex );

clObjectsGraph::const_iterator i = std::find( Env->ObjectsGraph.begin(), Env->ObjectsGraph.end(), Obj );

if ( i == Env->ObjectsGraph.end() ) return clPtr<iObject>();

bool IsSame  = Obj->FGeneration == Generation;
bool IsAlive = Obj->GetReferenceCounter() > 0;

return  ( IsSame && IsAlive ) ? clPtr<iObject>( Obj ) : clPtr<iObject>();
```

`Generation` is global in the scope of `sEnvironment` and is atomic-incremented every time a new object is instantiated.

**My questions are:**

1) Is it safe to implement weak-references like this?

2) Are there any ways to optimize the `clWeakPtr::Lock()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It seems safe indeed, but any modification of the graph will have some contention with `LPtr::GetObjectsGraphPtrWrapper`

2) a read-write lock could help, at least you'll be able to call several `Lock()` in parallel

The problem with your solution is that it defeats the locality that non-intrusive weak pointers bring.
Depending on the concurrency level, it might become a problem as each call to `Lock()` will prevent any object creation and as well any other `Lock()` call without a read-write lock.

Comment: if you have access to boost, you could use a boost::shared_mutex (as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244316/reader-writer-locks-in-c, there are also responses for Windows there), for pthreads (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635963/read-write-lock-implementation-using-mutex-only), your LPtr::GetObjectsGraphPtrWrapper would be a reader, and the function actually modifying the graph would be a writer. Note that it would protect only the graph and objects existence, not the objects content (unless your write-lock before modifying the objects, depends on your needs)